# Why does this VBA code not make any changes to my excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I want this to code for where if I put yes into a rowJ,"brain?" beside rowG for gene(s) in sheet C  then it finds that gene in sheet B and puts yes in rowJ in sheet B.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, do not link to code you wish to be commented. Provide the code here. Provide an [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to keep it short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that I wrote was putting "yes" where in sheet C where there was already a "yes."
To put "yes" in sheet B where value was found I used

```html
found.Offset(0,3).Value
```

instead of

```html
cell. Offset(0,3). Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Examining your Excel file on GitHub, I believe you are referring to method `inbrain()` in module `Module3`
(in the future, please include that info in your question).

I believe your typo resides on the `cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = brainB` line of this code block

```vb
    Dim mmc2 As Workbook: Set mmc2 = ThisWorkbook
    Dim shB As Worksheet
    Set shB = mmc2.Sheets("(B) Mouse thymocytes RAG1")
    Dim shC As Worksheet
    Set shC = mmc2.Sheets("(C) Mouse preB RAG1")

    Dim colG As Range
    Set colG = shC.Range("G3:G3388")

    For Each cell In colG
        Dim brain As String
        brain = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value

        Dim brainB As String

        If brain = "yes" Then
            Dim found As Range
            Set found = shB.Range("G3:G3537").Find(What:=cell.Value)

            If Not found Is Nothing Then
                brainB = "yes"
            End If
            cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = brainB
        End If
    Next cell
```

It should instead be `cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = brainB`

I would also expand the If statement to clear the cell if there is not a match, like this:

```vb
        If brain = "yes" Then
            Dim found As Range
            Set found = shB.Range("G3:G3537").Find(What:=cell.Value)

            If Not found Is Nothing Then
                brainB = "yes"
            End If
            cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = brainB
        Else
            cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = ""
        End If
```

Comment: Yes, sorry this is the inbrain() module. That did not fix it, the problem is that this code does not do anything to sheet B.